# Can I use case of a switch case inside if statement in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a=2,b=2;
    switch(a){
    case 1:
        cout<<"A"<<endl;
        if(b==5){
            case 2:
                cout<<"A"<<endl;
        }
    case 3:
        cout<<"A"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

not able to understand how this code outputs 2 "A"s,how can you put if statement outside of case

Comment: Read [this page](http://blog.robertelder.org/switch-statements-statement-expressions/), and you'll understand that case statements can be just about anything!

Comment: Short answer, you can. That's the same principle Duff's device is based on. But I don't think you should...

Comment: Why you put if in switch? Just make variable choice and put it in switch(choice) and when user inputs number of CHOICE that case will be selected in selection form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `break` anywhere, so when `case 2` is hit, it falls through to `case 3` and prints the second A.

If you used different output in each case that would have been a bit more obvious.

And yes the grammar lets you put the case inside an if, the same as it allowed  [duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) to compile.

Answer (score -1):

It outputs 2 `'A'`s since you provide no `break` statement.